# Restrict Minecraft server access to subdomain on a server that also reverse proxy’s Nginx sites?

Tags: networking, dns, minecraft, subdomain

I have a Minecraft server and a web server under `minecraft.example.com` but I have other web servers under different subdomains like `studio.example.com`, `download.example.com` etc…

I want to restrict, that my Minecraft server can be accessed only trough `minecraft.example.com`. I tried SRV records but they doesn't seem to work.

My web servers are behind a Nginx proxy server and a bind DNS server at `192.168.1.100`.

I have my Minecraft server at `192.168.1.47` at the default `25565` port.

---

If I open the port on my router, to `192.168.1.47` then I can to connect to the server with any of the subdomains. But when I open the port to my DNS server, where I already set the SRV record, I can not connect. I get a connection refused error message.

I have all these subdomains and Minecraft server under the same public IP address.

Can someone help me figure this out? I tried everything I found on the internet for a couple of weeks now but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What OS are you on? I assume Linux? This might be best handled by firewall rules? So for example all traffic on port `25565` can only be handled if the request comes from `minecraft.example.com`?

Comment: *"I want to restrict my Minecraft server so it can be accessed only through `minecraft.example.com`."* -- Unfortunately, I believe the short answer here is that you're probably unlikely to be able to do this. The reason protocols like `HTTP` and `HTTPS` can be "filtered" by webservers is that `HTTP/HTTPS` requests themselves retain e.g. `minecraft.example.com` in their headers, which can then be examined. However, to the best of my knowledge, Minecraft doesn't have a similar mechanism.

Comment: Regarding SRV records specifically, I believe these are simply used by Minecraft to make connections via domain names easier. I don't believe there is any ability to "block" connections with them in the manner you seem to desire.